# How to create the snapshots.img from console?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When creating a new AVD through the AVD manager it is possible to enable the snapshot feature by simply checking the right option in the "Create new AVD" window.

[image]

After creating the AVD you can find a file named `snapshots.img` under `<user-home>/.android/avd/<avd-name>/`. It is the snapshot storage file for the new AVD.

Does anybody know how to obtain the same result by using the command line tools?

I already tried creating a new AVD by using the `android create avd` command as well as setting the option `snapshot.present=true` in the AVD `config.ini`, but no snapshot storage is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to create the snapshot storage file.

The documentation to consider is the QEMU one. In particular, under Linux you can use the `qemu-img` tool (documentation [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/kvm-img.1.html)).

I created the `snapshots.img` file by using this command:

`qemu-img create -f qcow2 snapshots.img 500M`

Comment: The first time that you try to launch the emulator from the command line you got: " emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration.". Just launch the emulator using the -no-snapshot-load [ensuring before that you have a snapshot.img prelatorsent]. The emulator will start and when closing the snapshot.img will be saved. After that you can launch the emulator without the no-snapshot-load switch and the snapshot will be correctly loaded/saved

Comment: FYI, `-o compat=0.10` might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `android create avd --snapshot` which will create the snapshots.img file for you and set the `snapshot.present=true` flag.