# Saving Android emulator snapshot via telnet fails on "KO: No block device can accept snapshots"

Tags: android, android-emulator, telnet, android-virtual-device

I launched Android emulator. I connected to emulator using `telnet localhost 5554`.

When I try to save a snapshot with `avd snapshot save foo`, I get `KO: No block device can accept snapshots`.

When I try to list available snapshots with `avd snapshot list`, I get `KO: No available block device supports snapshots`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable snapshots for your virtual device.

In Eclipse: Window > Android Virtual Device Manager > select device > Edit > tick the Snapshots:Enabled checkbox

Answer (score 4):

The main reason of "no available block device" is that you do not assign the snapshot file to the emulator. You can restart your emulator with the following parameter:

```
emulator -snapstorage path/to/data/dir/snapshots.img
```

You can refer more information from "emulator -help".

PS: The snapshots.img uses a specific format and you cannot use just a blank file as the snapshot storage. You can see here for more information about creating a snapshot image:

[How to create the snapshots.img from console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896388/how-to-create-the-snapshots-img-from-console)

Comment: How do I load the saved snapshot when starting the `emulator` executable?

Comment: @naxa You can connect to the console and use "avd snapshot load <name>" to load the snapshot you have saved.